# Error al pasar matriz PHP a Javascript por medio de evento onclick y jsonencode

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

Estoy intentando enviar una matriz de datos que tengo almacenado en una variable en PHP a javascript por medio de `onclick()`.

Lo que tengo es la siguiente matriz PHP:

```
$apuesta = array("id"=>$idPartido, "cuota"=>$info_apuestas_L, "apostado"=>'local', "equipoL"=>$info_equipo_L, "equipoV"=>$info_equipo_V);
```

Luego lo convierto en JSON:

```
$apuestaJson = json_encode($apuesta);
```

Y mediante un botón lo intento enviar a javascript al momento de hacer clic así:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="clientes(<?php $apuestaJson ?>);" class="btnn"><?=  $info_apuestas_L ;?></button>
```

Por último, recibo la información en el script javascript así:

```
function clientes(e) {
    var apuesta = JSON.parse(e);
    alert("el array es:"+apuesta);

}
```

El `alert()` no se ejecuta y al intentar ver los datos. En consola el error me dice lo siguiente:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()

Agradezco si alguien me ayuda a enviar la matriz a la función javascript.

Comment: Hola amigo, la verdad dudo que este llegando correctamente este valor a **javascript**, lo que deberías hacer para comprobar eso es: Hacer un `console.log(e)` al inicio de toda tu función. O también un `var_dump($apuestaJson)` del lado de **PHP**

Comment: Y colocar ese resultado en tu pregunta, claro esta. Saludos

Comment: Me atrevo a decir que tu error esta en, la variable `$idPartido` tal vez, pero ya veremos eso

Comment: Creo que solo te falta enviar el contenido, un `echo` debería ser suficiente `<?php $apuestaJson ?>` porque no estás haciendo algo con esa variable.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder a todos, al depurar el array e imprimirlo en pantalla me muestra de manera correcta el json asi: {"ID":676387,"CUOTA":"1.36","APOSTADO":"LOCAL","EQUIPOL":"VALUR W","EQUIPOV":"THR\U00F3TTUR REYKJAV\U00EDK W"} Pero al ejecutar el boton y hacer un console.log(e) me da este error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Por favor, revisa mi respuesta. El error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" es probable que lo genere el código javascript mal generado en el atributo `onclick`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La parte inicial está bien:

```
$apuesta = array(
    "id" => $idPartido,
    "cuota" => $info_apuestas_L,
    "apostado" => 'local',
    "equipoL" => $info_equipo_L,
    "equipoV" => $info_equipo_V,
); 
$apuestaJson = json_encode($apuesta);
```

Pero en la parte de HTML deberías agregar [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/es/htmlspecialchars) para convertir las comillas dobles en entidades HTML para que no cierre el valor del atributo `onclick`:

```
<button
    type="button"
    onclick="clientes(<?= htmlspecialchars($apuestaJson) ?>);"
    class="btn"
><?= htmlspecialchars($info_apuestas_L) ?></button>
```

También deberías usarlo al enviar el contenido de `$info_apuestas_L` al navegador. En caso contrario tu página sería vulnerable a [ataques XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Por último, debes entender que al convertir datos de PHP en datos codificados en JSON, éstos son valores nativos de javascript y no deben decodificarse mediante `JSON.parse()`, si no que están listos para su uso directo en javascript:

```
function clientes(e) {
    console.log("El contenido de 'e' es:", e);
}
```

---

Ejemplo reproduciendo el código generado en PHP:

```js
function clientes(e) {
    console.log("El contenido de 'e' es:", e);
}
```

```html
<button
    type="button"
    onclick="clientes({id: 5, cuota: 400, apostado: &quot;local&quot;, equipoL: &quot;Equipo Local&quot;, equipoV: &quot;Equipo Visitante&quot;});"
    class="btn"
>Apuesta</button>
```

Debes notar que he tenido que usar la entidad `&quot;` en vez de comillas dobles para delimitar las cadenas que contienen el nombre de los equipos, en caso contrario se cerraría la declaración del valor del atributo `onclick`. Por eso hay que usar `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, cometí una errata al eliminar el punto y coma final de la entidad `&quot;` al copiar/pegar para agregar el valor de "local".

Comment: Oscar, muy interesante tu respuesta amigo, pero me surge una duda, ¿No es necesario que imprima el valor de este `string` en el **html** con un `echo` por ejemplo?, aunque use `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @Josbert, pero no es necesario usar una función de salida al navegador (como `echo`, `printf`, `vprintf`, etc) cuando se usa la etiqueta de salida al navegador `<?= ... ?>` (también llamada "etiqueta de `echo` abreviada"). Está disponible desde PHP 5.0 y su disponibilidad está garantizada sea cual sea la configuración de PHP desde PHP 5.4.0 (incluyendo desactivar [`short_open_tag`](https://php.net/es/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag)).

Comment: Mil gracias por tu tiempo para aclara mi duda amigo, la verdad había quedado un poco aturdido entre la duda, ya que recordaba que sin eso me ha llegado a funcionar pero no sabia porque, gracias de nuevo..!!

Comment: Amigo muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, diste con la solución muchísimas gracias me ayudaste mucho.

Comment: @OscarGarcia amigo me surge una ultima pregunta quizas tambien me puedas ayudar, estoy intentando enviar ahora ese array de vuelta a mi controlador pero la respuesta me llega vacía puedes decirme en que estoy fallando?                                                                                             var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXobjet('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
var ajaxUrl = base_url+'home/addApuesta';
var data = e;
request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
request.send(data);
console.log(request);

Comment: Lo siento @SebastianTorres , los comentarios no guardan el formato ni son un buen método para compartir código. Puedes crear una nueva pregunta y poner allí el código y el problema que sufres. Cuando lo hagas puedes dejarme un comentario con el enlace para que le eche un vistazo y, además, también podrán ayudarte y dar su opinión otros compañeros.

Comment: @OscarGarcia disculpame de ante mano por molestarte tanto, acabo de realizar el post te dejo el enlace por si deseas echarle un vistaso y ayudarme https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/470318/error-ajax-env%c3%ado-de-informaci%c3%b3n-al-controlador muchas gracias!

Comment: @OscarGarcia amigo buenas tardes, yo nuevamente por aca molestando, te queria consultar, el código funciona a la perfección pero solo lo puedo ejecutar 2 veces sin refrescar la pagina, a la tercera vez me genera el siguiente error me podrías ayudar? VM83:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange

Comment: Es código estático, debería funcionar tantas veces como se use. Es probable que otro código Javascript esté alterando algo, afectando al funcionamiento. ¿Podrías compartir el código completo que te está fallando para investigarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Como indica el compañero [@Triby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/54039/triby), te falta el `echo`:

```
<button type="button" onclick="clientes(<?php echo $apuestaJson; ?>);" class="btnn"><?=  $info_apuestas_L ;?></button>
```

O bien:

```
<button type="button" onclick="clientes(<?= $apuestaJson; ?>);" class="btnn"><?=  $info_apuestas_L ;?></button>
```