# Eliminar un elemento específico de un array(); en PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array(); con datos que voy almacenando en una variable de sesión "tipo carrito de compra" llamada `$_SESSION['carito']` algo así:

```
vardump($_SESSION['carito']);

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [evento] => 689382
            [cuota] => 2.10
            [equipoL] => Deportes Copiapo
            [equipoV] => Union San Felipe
            [tipo] => Match Winner
            [apostadoA] => local
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [evento] => 690693
            [cuota] => 1.50
            [equipoL] => Nautico Recife
            [equipoV] => Brasil DE Pelotas
            [tipo] => Match Winner
            [apostadoA] => local
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [evento] => 690695
            [cuota] => 3.00
            [equipoL] => CSA
            [equipoV] => Vasco DA Gama
            [tipo] => Match Winner
            [apostadoA] => empate
        )

);
```

y mediante un `foreach()` recorro los elemento del la variable `$_SESSION['carrito']` y los imprimo en pantalla de la siguiente manera.

```
<?php

foreach ($_SESSION['carrito'] as $producto) {

  $evento = $producto['evento'];
  $cuota = $producto['cuota'];
  $equipoL = $producto['equipoL'];
  $equipoV = $producto['equipoV'];
  $apuestaTipo = $producto['tipo'];
  $apostadoA = $producto['apostadoA'];
?>

<div class="widget-body contain-apuesta">
   <div class="pad">
       <p class="titulo-pad fw900"><?= $equipoL; ?> <span>VS</span> <?= $equipoV; ?></p>
       <div class="titulo-pad mt-b"><?= $apuestaTipo; ?></div>
       <div class="apuesta-cuota">
           <div class="ftp"><?= $cuota; ?></div>
           <div class="ftp"><?= $apostadoA; ?></div>
           <div onclick="dellCarrito(<?= $evento ?>);" class="ftp"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></div>
       </div>
       <form class="input-apuesta">
            <small>Valor a postar:</small>
            <input class="val-apuesta" type="text" name="campoValor" value="20">
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es eliminar un elemento del array identificándolo por medio de la variable `$evento = $producto['evento'];` que me regresa el id único de dicho elemento dentro del `array();` mediante `unset();`.

ejemplo: ¿como podría eliminar el elemento con indice`[evento]=>690695` del array mediante `unset();` o cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Agradezco mucho su ayuda, Muchísimas gracias

Comment: ¿Quieres borrar todos los índices `evento` de cada elemento? ¿O quieres borrar el registro completo cuyo `evento` valga `690695`? ¿O tu intención es eliminando de la matriz los elementos uno a uno conforme los hayas procesado? Es decir, ¿podrías explicar un poco más dónde quieres hacer el borrado y por qué motivo? quizá haya una manera más eficiente de hacerlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres eliminar un elemento de una variable de sesión mediante su valor debes buscar el índice donde se encuentra. Para esto puedes usar [`array_search()`](https://php.net/es/array_search) y dentro [`array_column`](https://php.net/es/array_column):

> `array_search` — Busca un valor determinado en un array y devuelve la
> primera clave correspondiente en caso de éxito.
>
> `array_column` — Devuelve los valores de una sola columna del array de
> entrada.

```
$evento = $producto['evento']; //dato 690695 

$key = array_search($evento, array_column($_SESSION['carrito'], 'evento'));

unset($_SESSION['carrito'][$key]);
```

Con `array_column()` traerá todos los valores de `$evento` y con `array_search()` buscamos el valor dentro de los resultados.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias muy valiosa tu respuesta, me ayudaste un monton

Comment: Este código no funciona correctamente para borrar el elemento completo de la matriz (solo el elemento `evento` de ese registro) y cuando no encuentra el elemento a borrar genera una advertencia que podría romper el contenido de la respuesta (si está activada la salida de mensajes al navegador). Te daré mi +1 si corriges el funcionamiento.

Comment: @OscarGarcian Gracias por tu observación, no hay nada que corregir ya que el autor de la pregunta solicito esto no todo el elemento de la matriz. No necesito puntos y si tu estas en busca de ellos dime y voy a votar tus respuestas y/o preguntas. Saludos

Comment: No lo hago por la búsqueda de puntos, lo hago porque me gusta valorar una buena respuesta, pero por desgracia a la tuya le falta hacer lo que el autor de la pregunta pidió: "eliminar el elemento con indice[evento]=>690695". En tu caso estás borrando solo el índice "evento" del elemento encontrado, no el elemento completo encontrado. Te hago la edición y te doy mi +1.